# A Segmentation fault in C

Tags: c

When I'm trying to run the code it shows the segmentation fault, what might be wrong here? This is an algorithm of quick sorting I wrote. Seems like I forgot to initialize the pointer or problem is in another thing. Who can fix it and explain what cause the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 10

void quicksort(int *array, int first, int last);

int main()
{
  int array[size] = {90, 10, 0, 15, 7, 9, -2, 6, 88, 17};
  printf("Before sorting: \n");
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", array[I]);
  quicksort(array, 0, size - 1);
  printf("\nAfter sorting: \n");
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", array[I]);
}

void quicksort(int *array, int first, int last)
{
    if(first < last)
    {
      int left = first;
      int right = last;
      int pivot = array[left + (right - left) / 2];
    do
    {
        while(array[left] < pivot)
        left++;
        while(array[right] > pivot)
        right++;
        if(left <= right)
        {
            int tmp = array[left];
            array[left] = array[right];
            array[right] = tmp;
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    } while(left <= right);
    quicksort(array, first, right);
    quicksort(array, left, last);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: for starters, you are accessing `array[I]` instead of `array[i]`

Comment: And you are incrementing the `right` value that is already the max index of the array.

Comment: Further, your code is badly formatted, which makes it harder to read, understand and fix.

Comment: Before doing `left++`, check that `left < last`. There may be multiple errors like this in your code.

Comment: From @Kyrex answer, what you want to do there is right—

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, how can I do it more readable?

Comment: Use an autoindenter. Many IDEs come with tools that automatically format your code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 10

void quicksort(int *array, int first, int last);

int main()
{
        int array[size] = {90, 10, 0, 15, 7, 9, -2, 6, 88, 17};
        printf("Before sorting: \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                printf("%d ", array[i]);
        quicksort(array, 0, size - 1);
        printf("\nAfter sorting: \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                printf("%d ", array[i]);
}

void quicksort(int *array, int first, int last)
{
        if(first < last)
        {
                int left = first;
                int right = last;
                int pivot = array[left + (right - left) / 2];

                do
                {
                        while(array[left] < pivot)
                                left++;
                        while(array[right] > pivot)
                                right--;
                        if(left <= right)
                        {
                                int tmp = array[left];
                                array[left] = array[right];
                                array[right] = tmp;
                                left++;
                                right--;
                        }
                } while(left <= right);

                quicksort(array, first, right);
                quicksort(array, left, last);
        }

        return;
}
```